# How to relate two Django models without Foreign Key in Django Rest Framework using PostgreSQL DB

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

If I was to have two Django models as shown below with Book related to Category, how else can i show the relation without using a Foreign Key when using Django Rest Framework using PostgreSQL DB to make the Foreign Key field editable in a HTML form?

```
CATEGORIES = [
    ('Fiction', ('Fiction')),
    ('Non-Fiction', ('Non-Fiction'))
]

class Category(models.Model):
   category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORIES)

class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   pages = models.IntergerField(max_length=255)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My challenge comes up in the DB when in the `book` table the category column in represented as `category_id` which are integers. This creates a problem as when performing CRUD functions especially `EDIT` since i can't edit the category from the front-end in a form because it's represented as i.e. `1,2,3.....` instead of the actual categories. I want to achieve this with a REST API.

My serializer

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

My API views

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def AddBookAPI(request):
    serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['PUT'])
def EditBookAPI(request, id):
    book_record =get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    serializer = BookSerializer(instance=book_record, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def DeleteBookAPI(request, id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    book.delete()

    return Response('Book Record Successfully Deleted!', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And a sample response

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "The Green Light",
        "author": "Peris Fuller",
        "pages": 456,
        "category": 2,
    },
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be okay to have the `id` for `categories`.
If you want to edit from the frontend, make a `get` request to get all categories (you did not report `category` serializer, but there must be `id` and `category_name`).

I guess you want to change categories via a select menu. If so, associate each option with the `id` of each category as a value and the `category_name` of each category as the text to be displayed.

When you go to edit the model, you will serialize `id` again, but you will be able to read the `category_name`.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your response led me to the right direction. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add `__str__` or `__unicode__` methods in your models that will help you to show the name instead of id on the UI.

Like this shared the example of both methods:-

```
class Category(models.Model):
   category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORIES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```

In your `BookSerializer` you can lookup for the id or name into the `Category` model and map the values accordingly.

Comment: i had the `__str__` and `__unicode__` in my code. I just hadn't placed it in my question. But thanks all the same.